# VBA: Remove a formatted date from the end of a file everyday and resave

Tags: excel, vba

every day I receive an automated file saved in the format DailyFile 09-12-18.xlsx.

I have written a VBA module to find a file called (in this case) DailyFile and update my necessary spreadsheets with the new daily data.

However, I need a way to cut the date portion off of the daily file so that my module can identify it, but I also need to keep a copy of EVERY daily file (with the date in the file name) for my records.

In other words, my master spreadsheet needs to pull the most up-to-date data from the daily file (which can be overwritten from yesterday), but I also want to save a copy of the original.

Here's what I have so far... It isn't working:

```
Option Explicit


Sub changefilename()

Dim tdate As Variant
Dim ofile As Workbook
Dim TestFile As String



tdate = Date
tdate.NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yy"

Set ofile = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Research\Documents\Daily File " & tdate & ".xlsx")
ofile.SaveAs Filename:=TestFile


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.NumberFormat` is a cell property. `tdate` is not a cell, but a Variant, thus doesn't have that property.

Use the `Format` function to format it instead:

```
Option Explicit

Sub changefilename()

    Dim tdate As Variant
    Dim ofile As Workbook
    Dim TestFile As String

    tdate = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy")

    Set ofile = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Research\Documents\Daily File " & tdate & ".xlsx")
    ofile.SaveAs Filename:=TestFile

End Sub
```

Comment: Figured out a similar method myself. Didn't realize how .NumberFormat worked. Used Format()... worked like a charm. See my solution.

Comment: @user10354299 notice how this answer *explains what and why*, rather than simply handing out a code dump. An answer like this is much more useful to people googling solutions to a similar problem, which is ultimately what this site is all about; consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking the hollow checkmark.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I purposefully left `tdate` as a variant, because I try to change as few as possible to make it easy to track down what actually caused the error. If I were to rewrite this, I'd probably leave out the variable altogether and just directly concatenate it. Same goes for why `TestFile` has no value.

Comment: That's fair, different strokes

Comment: @MathieuGuindon yes, I frequent the site for help. Explanation is much appreciated--i know how far it goes for people with similar issues. Just was proud of solving it myself...wanted to share.

Comment: @user10354299 no harm self-answering at all, it's even encouraged! if your answer *explained* what was going on, I'd absolutely have given it an upvote =) keep up the good work!

Answer (score 3):

```
 Option Explicit 

    Sub changefilename()

 Dim ofile As Workbook
 Dim TestFile As String 


    '##What we want the new save file to be called, with path:
TestFile = "C:\Users\Research\Documents\TEST.xlsx"


    '##Searches for a file that concats the file name with today's date.
    '##Use format(Date,____) for how your date is formatted. No need to assign a variable to the Date.
Set ofile = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Research\Documents\DailyFile" & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy") & ".xlsx")

       '##Saves the old file in the desired path!
ofile.SaveAs Filename:=TestFile


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub changefilename()

    Dim tdate As String
    Dim ofile As Workbook
    Dim ofile_Name As String

    tdate = Format(Date, "MM-DD-YY")

    Set ofile = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Research\Documents\Daily File " & tdate & ".xlsx")

    'change the character 9 to whatever the length of the file name
    ofile_Name = Left(ofile.Name, 9)

    ofile.SaveAs Filename:=ofile_Name   

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you meant `ofile.SaveAs Filename:=ofile_Name`

Comment: Personally I think I would just do `ofile_Name = ofile.path & "\Daily File.xlsx"` instead of `Left(...)`